# Is there an Adobe Flash Player 10 Windows Merge Module available?

Tags: flash

The admin guide for flash 8/9 suggests there's a .msm (merge module) for windows? I'm not seeing a merge module for flash 10. Does such a thing exist and if so where?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using merge modules as they can not be updated. Since Flash gets regularly updates I would just use Adobe's standard installer.

If you want to redistribute the flash player with your application check out this link:
http://www.adobe.com/products/players/fpsh_distribution1.html

Comment: We have a license already. The merge module is best for us since the client machine does not have access to the internet and they want it all in one installer.